# MouseMove event not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Binded a mousemove event for a path element as below

```
    $(seriesRender.gSeriesGroupEle.childNodes[pointIndex]).bind('mousemove', seriesRender.onChartMove);

 onChartMove: function(evt){
    debugger;
      },
```

this function get triggered in IE and chrome, but not in firefox, is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 3):

i had did some time ago like,

```
$('#control-vol').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    $('#control-vol').bind('mousemove', function(e){
         // my stuff
    });

    $('#control-vol').bind('mouseup',function(){
        $('#control-vol').unbind('mousemove')
    });
});
```

Also refer below demo link

http://jsbin.com/icuso/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem  the mousemove event was not working reliably, only firing then the button state or focussed window changed. I cured this by logging out of and back in to my desktop environment.